# Prevent refresh on enter. while in input box

Tags: jquery, inputbox

Whenever input box is in focus, Enter results in page refresh. I want to prevent refresh on enter and put an event on it. Here's what i came up with, but this triggers Enter to refresh:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#textboxid").on('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        $("#textboxid").animate({
        color: '#FFF'
    }, 2000, function () {
        $(this).val('').css('color', 'black');
    }); 
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code . add [e.preventDefault();](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) when  keyCode is 13

you can check condition on keydown event . which fires when user press enter.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#textboxid").on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.which === 13){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#textboxid").animate({
       color: '#FFF'
      }, 2000, function () {
       $(this).val('').css('color', 'black');
    }); 
   }
 });
});
```

Or use `return false` to prevent page refresh

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#textboxid").on('keydown', function(e){
    if( e.which === 13){
      $("#textboxid").animate({
       color: '#FFF'
      }, 2000, function () {
       $(this).val('').css('color', 'black');
    }); 
    return false;
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: Great ;) . keydown fires first